# Sniff and edit TCP traffic in Python

Tags: python, flash, sniffing

I am developing proxy for Flash game, it must sniff all the traffic from the game, edit some of it and send to the game main server, where requests are directed. I searched for solutions, but i've founded only solutions with using Wireshark or Python one's that can't sniff content, only ports and IPs.

Comment: You cannot modify a packet which is sent to some other server. What you can is play the middleman - have the client connect to you (pretend to be the server) and then you relay the messages to the actual server (pretend to be the client). Do the same with messages going in the other direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use mitmproxy which is an open source and interactive TLS-capable HTTP proxy interceptor. It has a web interface and a Python API. Check below pages if it meets your needs.

https://mitmproxy.org

https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy